# Crontab -e no publica mis tweets cada hora

Tags: python, crontab

hace un par de días estuve investigando a cerca de la API de Twitter para poder aprender un poco y poder programar mis tweets sin límites (cómo ponen iftt, metricool, de X tweets al mes/día).

Primero hice un script simple con Python que publica un tweet cada vez que se ejecuta, el cual es el siguiente:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import tweepy

#Coloca dentro de las comillas tus claves...

CONSUMER_KEY = 'llave'

CONSUMER_SECRET = 'llave'

ACCESS_KEY = 'llave'

ACCESS_SECRET = 'llave'

#En esta parte nos identifica para poder realizar operaciones

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)

auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)

#update_status('mensaje' o variable) es para actualizar nuestro estado

x = tweepy.API(auth)

x.update_status('Tweet a publicar')
```

Si ejecuto el script, el tweet se publica sin ningún problema. Por ello pensé en escribir varios scripts con el mismo programa, pero que tuviesen distintos mensajes a publicar y después configurarlos en un crontab -e para que se fuesen ejecutando todos ellos automáticamente en mi servidor.
Todos ellos tienen permisos de ejecución y el crontab -e está definido de esta manera:

```
06 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/user/web.py

16 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/user/libro.py

36 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/user/crowd.py

45 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/user/wattpad.py
```

En principio, debería publicar tweets en los minutos 6,16, 36 y 45 de todas las horas de todos los días, pero ni publica todos los tweets ni lo hace todas las horas.
No entiendo que patrón está siguiendo, ya que a veces los publica y otras no.

Estuve mirando en el developer.twitter.com, por si ellos también habían puesto un límite, pero por lo que vi tenían un límite de 2 millones por mes, y estás publicaciones no llegan ni a 3 mil al mes.

Comment: ¿Qué arroja `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`?

Comment: He utilizado ```grep CRON /var/log/syslog | grep user | wc -l``` para ver el número de veces que se ha "ejecutado" el cron, y me indica que 67 veces, pero solo me aparecen los del día de hoy. Además, el último tweet que se me ha publicado es a las 11:06, pero desde entonces no me publica más y el log sigue hasta las 16:45

Comment: Copie tu crontab (con .py vacios) y fuciona correctamente (Linux Mint 20)

Comment: ¿Y te funciona todo el tiempo? Cómo te digo, hay veces que no me publica el tweet, a pesar de que el log de crontab diga que se haya ejecutado.

Comment: Según las pruebas, el cron funciona a sus horas. Si falla el tweet, es problema de la aplicación, la conexión Internet, el servidor Twitter o alguna otra cosa. Yo agregaría código para logear el inicio, resultado y termino de cada ejecución.

Comment: De acuerdo, gracias